# src/main/java folder not visible in project explorer in Spring Roo project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I followed these excellent instructions:

http://baldercm.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/maven-multi-module-with-spring-roo-and.html

I now have a multi-module roo / jsf / jpa project up and running in STS.

However I notice I have no `src/java` folder in any of my projects?

I do have a package path under `src/main/java` in the project explorer, which when I explore the files seem to point to here:

```
/Users/me/Documents/Java Projects/Projects/AdminDirect/AdminDirect-Model/src
/main/java/com/astrazeneca/rd/model/Foo.java
```

But apart from the package explorer, under src/main folder in the project explorer there is only src/main?

In my projects at work you seem able to navigate to the java classes either via the package explorer or a mirror folder structure under `src/main/java/xxxxx`?

My project is in a separate folder to my workspace, and I imported it into the workspace.  Builds and runs fine.

Comment: This question is not directly related to JSF at all.

Comment: Sorry, in the JSF zone at the moment.  I have removed JSF tag.